# How does Spark use Netty?

Tags: netty, apache-storm, apache-spark

I know that Storm now runs on Netty for communication betwen nodes?

Does Apache Spark also use Netty? If so, in what way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spark uses Akka Actor for RPC and messaging, which in turn uses Netty.

Also, for moving bulk data, Netty is used.

- For shuffle data, Netty can be optionally used. By default, NIO is directly used to do transfer shuffle data.
- For broadcast data (driver-to-all-worker data transfer), Jetty is used by default.

Comment: Is it Jetty or Netty ?

Comment: Akka is not used in Spark since Spark 1.6. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448757/why-spark-1-6-does-not-use-akka